# Odoo: Search records from model and copy to other model

Tags: python, one-to-many, odoo, recordset, many-to-one

I have 2 classes in Odoo: opc_taginstellingen en opc_actuelewaardentags.

In opc_taginstellingen I have fields tagnaam and unit.

In opc_actuelewaardentags, I also have a field tagnaam and unit.

What I want to do is compare tagnaam and retrieve the unit from opc_actuelewaardentags.

If opc_actuelewaardentags.tagnaam == opc_taginstellingen.tagnaam then retrieve opc_taginstellingen.unit and copy it to opc_actuelewaardentags.unit.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
class opc_taginstellingen(models.Model):
    _name = 'opc_taginstellingen'

    tagnaam = fields.Char(string="Tagnaam")
    unit = fields.Char(string="unit")
    tag_instellingen = fields.Many2one('opc_actuelewaardentags')

class opc_actuelewaardentags(models.Model):
    _name = 'opc_actuelewaardentags'

    tagnaam = fields.Char(string="Tagnaam")
    tag_instelling = fields.One2many(comodel_name='opc_taginstellingen', inverse_name='tag_instellingen')

    @api.one
    def changeUnit(self):
        instellingen = self.env['opc_taginstellingen'].search([('id','=',self.tag_instelling.id)])
        ret = ""
        for instelling in instellingen:
            ret = instelling.unit
            print ret
        return ret

    unit = fields.Char(default=changeUnit, string="unit1")
```

But this code doesn't work.
I think it doesn't even get to changeUnit...

I have also tried
`@api.multi` instead of `@api.one`
and

`unit = fields.Char(compute='changeUnit', string="unit1")` instead of

`unit = fields.Char(default=changeUnit, string="unit1")`

Does anyone have any idea why this code isn't working?

If my explanation is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
class opc_taginstellingen(models.Model):
    _name = 'opc.taginstellingen'

    tagnaam = fields.Char(string="Tagnaam")
    unit = fields.Char(string="unit")
    tag_instellingen = fields.Many2one('opc_actuelewaardentags')

class opc_actuelewaardentags(models.Model):
    _name = 'opc.actuelewaardentags'

    tagnaam = fields.Char(string="Tagnaam")
    tag_instelling = fields.One2many('opc.taginstellingen')

    def changeUnit(self):
        for opc_tag in self.tag_instelling:
        if opc_tag.tagnaam==self.tagnaam:
           return opc_tag.unit

    unit = fields.Char(default=changeUnit, string="unit1")
```